# VB-Launch file from an auto complete Combo Box

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I'm having problem with my program. I cannot execute files from a specific directory when I use AutoCompleteCustomSource. Can someone please take a look at my codes and tell me what's wrong

Thank you in advance

```
Public Class Form1
Private Execute As New List(Of String)

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ComboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
    ComboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    Dim files() As String
    files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("D:\Documents")
    For Each f As String In files
        Execute.Add(f)
        ComboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f))

    Next
    If ComboBox1.Items.Count > 0 Then ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
        Process.Start(Execute(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex))
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the ComboBox or its AutoComplete feature. Bcoz, on the click event of the Button, you are trying to invoke a process whose FULLPATH is stored in the Execute variable.

Try adding a BreakPoint inside the Button1_Click() method to see whether or not the PATH in the Execute list is correct. Alternatively, you can also add a `MsgBox(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex)` before the `Process.Start()` to verify the same.

Also, make sure that the Path of the file is surrounded in quotes.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
        Dim fullPath = Execute(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex)
        fullPath = String.Format("""{0}""", fullPath) 'surround with quotes
        Process.Start(fullPath)
    End If
End Sub
```

If this doesnt works, you may try the [ProcessStartInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) class to debug the issue.